# use opencl in NVIDIA problem: cl.h without clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties()

Tags: opencl, nvidia

when i want to use opencl in NVIDIA, met a compile error，
error: ‘clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties’ was not declared in this scope
clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties() is used to init opencl.

i didn't find clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties() in cl.h
so i don't how to init opencl in nvidia.(other code also use clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties() to init opencl in nvidia )
[image: NVIDIA and opencl info]